# Why is this assembly failing strong name validation?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll, strongname

I am using CabLib.dll in my C# project from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15397/Cabinet-File-CAB-Compression-and-Extraction

I am using Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10.

When I try and publiah the app, I get this error: `Strong name signature not valid for this assembly CabLib.dll.`

```
System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (SignatureValidation)
    - Strong name signature not valid for this assembly CabLib.dll.
    - Source: System.Deployment
    - Stack trace:
        at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentVerifier.VerifyStrongNameAssembly(String filePath, AssemblyManifest assemblyManifest)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentVerifier.VerifyComponents()
        at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDependencies(SubscriptionState subState, AssemblyManifest deployManifest, AssemblyManifest appManifest, Uri sourceUriBase, String targetDirectory, String group, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
```

I can use the SN.exe tool from the VS Dev Cmd Prompt and get the public token for the .dll, but when I use `SN -v cablib.dll` I get the error `Failed to verify assembly -- Strong name validation failed.`

Where can I get more information on this failure?

Comment: first, add your ca cert to IE/Edge, then recheck your project's signing config. I did that under win7+vs2013.

Comment: old question, but just for the record, this comment may be related: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15397/Cabinet-File-CAB-Compression-and-Extraction?msg=5367329#xx5367329xx